# right way to implement secrets caching in aws secrets manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

Hi I have implemented secrets caching as per this [repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-python). Essentially added the following piece of code:

```py
session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
try: 
    # create a cache
    cache_config = SecretCacheConfig(secret_refresh_interval=14400) # refresh cache every 4 hours
    cache = SecretCache(config=cache_config, client=client)
    # get secret string from the cache
    get_secret_value_response = cache.get_secret_string(secret_name)
except ClientError as e:
    raise e
```

But I am unsure if it is working, as the time taken by api call on subsequent requests has not decreased. It still stays the same (roughly) to what it was before caching.

Is there a way to verify to if caching is working or is it the right way to implement it?

--- Edit
Before caching I was fetching secrets as follows:

```py
secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
```

Basically I removed the above piece of code and added caching code instead of it.

Comment: The code that you have here is going to recreate the cache every time it's called. Is that how you're using the cache, or do you have different code that retrieves values? If you have different code, please show that code.

Comment: I am unsure of how to do then, I was referring their [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/improve-availability-and-latency-of-applications-by-using-aws-secret-managers-python-client-side-caching-library/), and added as shown there. Is this not the right way?

Comment: I have modified the question to show, how I was fetchign the secrets before. But I removed this part assuming, fetching of secrets and caching it will be taken care by SecretCache object.

Comment: Can you confirm if this code is in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

You must not recreate the cache anytime.
You create it once and reuse it later either with the method call or with the decorator:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-decor-string.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment variable to load the variables at the time of the initialization and use that variable in the project repo. This will help you organize your code as well as help you save costs in AWS by minimizing the number of requests to the secret manager. This can be configured using Github Action in CI/ CD pipeline.